# how to resolve ssl.SSLCertVerificationError from python on a Mac

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I am running python 3.9 on a Mac and in my python code I get

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

the URL is a valid one with a valid certificate and I can get to it with a browser just fine. the URL is

```
https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_OnQppLqYQ....
```

I read many Install.certificate articles and that has not helped my issue.

Any suggestions here?